# Android9.0 InputMethod out of screen range

Tags: android

I add Left NavigationBar with TYPE_NAVIGATION_BAR_PANEL，and set privateFlags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.PRIVATE_FLAG_IS_SCREEN_DECOR;
But InputMethod going out of screen. 
What should I do to solve this problem?
[click to see the screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOZI7.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the keyboard. If you create your own keyboard that just shows a simple view, you will see that it works as expected